# Storing 2D Grid of objects

Tags: java, big-o

I am creating a game where I have a 2D grid of `Tile` objects. Each of these `Tile` objects have a number of instance variables containing objects like `Tower` and `View`.

I am currently implementing this grid as a HashMap from `Point` (awt) to `Tile` object. Is this a good way of implementing the grid? This allows me to not map certain points that don't have a `Tile` object yet.

The alternative would be to have a `Tile[][]`, but that would require enough memory to be pre-allocated for the entire grid, even if no tile exists, right?

Both of these are also stored on the heap but I'd like to know performance/space differences between the two implementation.

Comment: How many rows and columns do you have?

Comment: These `Tile` objects are visually displayed at around 5-20 pixels height and width, so anywhere between 10x10 to 200x200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions (`HashMap<Point, Tile>` and `new Tile[200][200]`) would work. I think I'd go for the simpler solution (the array) unless you have very good reason to think memory is an issue. You are correct that `new Tile[200][200]` allocates memory for the entire grid even if there are no `Tile`s. Remember `HashMap` requires a lot of memory as each key/value pair is wrapped in an `Entry` object, so the map solution may not save memory unless the grid is sparse.

Comment: So, if my `Tile` objects are large, then use HashMap. Thanks